# linux virtualbox guest (windows host) to physical partition

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, partition, v2p

I'm currently running a linux virtual machine on a windows XP host with virtualbox(3.1.2) and I would like to copy it and run it on a partition of my machine. I want to use my vm as primary os but keep my windows partition (in case).

- How to copy the vm to a phisical disk?
- Will there be any issue with grub?

Any lead?

Answer (score 1):

Try running [CloneZilla](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-clonezilla/?ca=dgr-lnxw06Clonezilla&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grlnxw06) 'backwards' (from virtual to physical), I *think* it should work. Or buy a copy of [Norton Ghost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost)

**EDIT**:
Of course you need to run it once 'forwards' also if you want to move the XP to inside the VM.